# Why does installing Shadow of Mordor from DVD take so incredibly long?

Tags: xbox-one, middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

While I'm computer savvy, I know nothing about modern gaming systems. We bought our son a pre-owned Xbox 1 for Christmas, along with a pre-owned game of Shadow of Mordor (and other games).

He tried installing Shadow of Mordor, and it was taking a very long time, until it got to 86% and just hung. It stayed at 86% for about half an hour before he gave up, rebooted and started trying to install it again. This time it (eventually) got to 81% before hanging.

Is this normal behavior for Xbox 1 games and is patience the only solution, or is this a sign that something is wrong with either the Xbox 1 or the game, or is there something else possibly wrong? (I don't think it should matter, but we have a reasonably fast fiber-optic connection to the Internet.)

Edit to add: After trying it a third time, he tried disconnecting from the Internet based on advice he found elsewhere (again, this is from a DVD, not from the internet), but that didn't help and possibly hurt. This time, when he got to 81% he just waited it out. A half hour later (now) and it's at 82%. So, it's apparently not *stopped* installation, it's just going very slowly.

Edit next day to add: While leaving it overnight to finish installing, it had still not finished when I woke up. However, by the time my son woke up a second time (he'd woken up earlier to see if it had finished), it did indeed finish installing — taking more than 12 hours to install!

Comment: It sounds a lot like the disk is damaged. Return the disk if you can, try to only get new disks. I'd recommend a budget gaming computer instead of an xbox one as you can get tons of games for free. Potentially might not even need to pay for games. Xbox games cost up to 60 dollars a disk, and if you buy it used it might just do what your game did and never work.

Comment: I recently purchased this game and can account for the same issues. It will also let you play earlier, but singleplayer is locked untill completed

Comment: Forgot to mention it took all night but installed successfully. From observation, Microsoft the percebtage thing oddly. If theres three packages of data, for instance, each one makes up 33.3%. Even if one package is 1mb and the other is 4 gb.